# cutting a sphere with 3 planes and calculating 8 sub-volumes using R-language

Tags: r, volume, integral

I want to calculate 8 sub-volumes (V) resulting from intersection of an sphere with Center coordinate (10.5,10.5,10.5) and r=1 with three palnes (x=10, y=10 and z=10). I am using R-Language and this is my code. I can calculate the volume of 2 parts of sphere correctly. I don't understand why it does not calculate the correct value for the other 6 sub-volumes.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
# the Center of the sphere
x <- 10.5
y <- 10.5
z <- 10.5
r <- 1

# the Box size and number of walls in each direction
U   <- 3
lBx <- 30
lBy <- 30
lBz <- 30

V   <- U^2
W   <- U^3

Ui <- U - 1
# Initiation of the walls
lx <- c()
ly <- c()
lz <- c()
# Position of the walls
for(i in 1:Ui){

  lx[i] <- i*lBx/U
  ly[i] <- i*lBy/U
  lz[i] <- i*lBz/U
}
# calculating the absolute distances between the Center of sphere and wall
# this is for calculation of xmin and xmid and xmax for calculation of integrals
dx <- sapply(x,function(x) lx - x)
abs.dx <- apply(abs(dx),2,min)
dx <- abs.dx*(2*(apply(replace(dx,which(dx<0),Inf),2,min)==abs.dx)-1)

dy <- sapply(y,function(y) ly - y)
abs.dy <- apply(abs(dy),2,min)
dy <- abs.dy*(2*(apply(replace(dy,which(dy<0),Inf),2,min)==abs.dy)-1)

dz <- sapply(z,function(z) lz - z)
abs.dz <- apply(abs(dz),2,min)
dz <- abs.dz*(2*(apply(replace(dz,which(dz<0),Inf),2,min)==abs.dz)-1)

#distance between radius center to intersection wall


d  <- (dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2 

dxy <- (dx)^2+(dy)^2
dyz <- (dy)^2+(dz)^2
dxz <- (dx)^2+(dz)^2

d1      <- apply(matrix(rbind(dxy,dyz,dxz),nrow=3,ncol=length(x)),2,min)
d2      <- matrix(rbind(dx,dy,dz),nrow=3,ncol=length(x))
abs.d2  <- matrix(rbind(abs.dx,abs.dy,abs.dz),nrow=3,ncol=length(x))
d11     <- apply(abs.d2,2,min)

X <- c()
Y <- c()
Z <- c()

vol <- c()

library('pracma')

for(j in 1:length(x)) {

  if (d[j] < r[j]^2) {

    f1 <- function(x, y)  (sqrt(r[j]^2 -x^2 - y^2) - abs.dz[j])
    f2 <- function(x, y)  (2*(sqrt(r[j]^2 - x^2 - y^2))) 
    f3 <- function(x, y)  (sqrt(r[j]^2 -x^2 - y^2))
    f4 <- function(x, y)  (sqrt(r[j]^2 -x^2 - y^2)- dz[j])

    xmin <- (-sqrt(r[j]^2-dy[j]^2-dz[j]^2)) 
    xmid <- dx[j] 
    xmax <- (sqrt(r[j]^2-dy[j]^2-dz[j]^2))  

    ymin <- function(x) (-(sqrt(r[j]^2-dz[j]^2-x^2))) 
    ymid <- dy[j]
    ymax <- function(x) (sqrt(r[j]^2-dz[j]^2-x^2))

    Vol1  <- integral2(f1, xmin, xmid, ymin, ymid)
    Vol2  <- integral2(f1, xmid, xmax, ymin, ymid)

    Vol3  <- integral2(f1, xmin, xmid, ymid, ymax)
    Vol34 <- integral2(f2, xmin, xmid, ymid, ymax)
    Vol5  <- integral2(f1, xmid, xmax, ymin, ymid)
    Vol56 <- integral2(f2, xmid, xmax, ymin, ymid)
    Vol7  <- integral2(f1, xmid, xmax, ymid, ymax)
    Vol78 <- integral2(f2, xmid, xmax, ymid, ymax)
 # finding the position of the calculated Volumes    
Vol8.1 <- Vol1$Q 
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.1 
Vol8.2 <- Vol2$Q
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.2
Vol8.3 <- Vol3$Q 
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.3
Vol8.4 <- Vol34$Q - Vol8.3
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.4
Vol8.5 <- Vol5$Q 
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.5
Vol8.6 <- Vol56$Q - Vol8.5
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.6
Vol8.7 <- Vol7$Q 
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.7
Vol8.8 <- Vol78$Q - Vol8.7
vol[[length(vol)+1]]=Vol8.8
     }
}
newdata <- cbind(X,Y,Z,vol)
newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
newdata
#AutoCad Check shows different values
#Volume1:0.0019 - Bounding box:X: 9.7929--10.0000/Y:9.7929--10.0000/Z:9.7929--10.0000
#Volume2:0.0609 - Bounding box:X: 9.6340--10.0000/Y:9.6340--10.0000/Z:10.000--11.2071
#Volume3:0.5308 - Bounding box:X: 9.5000--10.0000/y:10.000--11.36607Z:10.000--11.3660
#Volume4:0.5308 - Bounding box:X: 10.000--11.3660/Y:9.5000--10.0000/Z:10.000--11.3660
#Volume5:0.0609 - Bounding box:X: 10.000--11.2071/Y:9.6340--10.0000/Z:9.6340--10.0000
#Volume6:0.0609 - Bounding box:X: 9.6340--10.0000/Y:10.000--11.2071/Z:9.6340--10.0000
#Volume7:2.4117 - Bounding box:X: 10.000--11.5000/Y:10.000--11.5000/Z:10.000--11.5000
#Volume8:0.5308 - Bounding box:X: 10.000--11.3660/Y:10.000--11.3660/Z:9.5000--10.0000
```

The results of R is as following:

```
      vol
1 0.001900686
2 0.060883156
3 0.051049453
4 0.282041684
5 0.060883156
6 0.399931778
7 0.520997769
8 2.067153172
```

Does anyone have an idea? Why the result of These 2 integrals are correct

```
            Vol1  <- integral2(f1, xmin, xmid, ymin, ymid)
            Vol2  <- integral2(f1, xmid, xmax, ymin, ymid)
```

and for the rest, some volumes which I don't know how R calculates them.